# how to simplify XSLT regex-group in matching-substring to an easier mataintain line

Tags: java, xml, xslt

Hi I recently use XSLT to split a txt message into xml file however the problem arise when I use xsl:matching-substring due too too many regex, I have to count the regex-group(n). Is there anyway I could simplify these method?

this what I am doing:

```
<xsl:variable name="lineA" as ="xs:string" select="'SAMPLE\+TEXT:1\+((\S+)?):ZZ\+((\S+)?):ZZ\+((\d+)?):((\d+)?)\+((\S+)?)'"/>
<xsl:variable name="lineB" as ="xs:string" select="'SAMPLE\+ALPHA:2\+((\S+)?):ZZ\+((\S+)?):ZZ\+((\d+)?):((\d+)?)\+((\S+)?)'"/>
<xsl:variable name="lineC" as ="xs:string" select="'SAMPLE\+BETA:3\+((\S+)?)\+((\S+)?):ZZ\+((\d+)?):((\d+)?)\+((\S+)?)'"/>
```

there are about total of 30++ lines

thus I use:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$lines">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." flags="x"
        regex="({$lineA})\r?\n?({$lineB})?\r?\n?({$lineC})?\r?\n?({$lineD})?\r?\n?({$lineE}).....>
```

The .... is till line 30++

Then I use:

```
<xsl:matching-substring>
   <line level="0"
        variableA="{regex-group(1)}"
        variableB="{regex-group(2)"
        variableC="{regex=group(3)"
        variableD="{regex=group(4)"
```

this could lead me to count the above regex from top to bottom till 30++ individual lines to get the regex-group it is hard to maintain..

is there a simpler way to work this out to maintain this lines of codes?

Comment: It might help if you try to post a simplified but complete  sample of input, wanted output and currently working XSLT. I currently not sure whether you want to replace e.g. `variableA="{regex-group(1)}" variableB="{regex-group(2)}" variableC="{regex-group(3)}" variableD="{regex=group(4)"` with some `<xsl:for-each select="1 to 4"><xsl:attribute name="variable{format-integer(., 'A')}" select="regex-group(.)"/></xsl:for-each>` or which rules there are to simplify the expression.

Comment: It might also help if you tell us which XSLT processor you use as perhaps with a recent version there is support for XPath 3.0/3.1 using the function `analyze-string` which then might make processing the result of the matching more flexible as it returns an XML structure easier to process with XSLT/XPath than the result of `xsl:analyze-string`

Answer (score 0):

I find it usually helps to decompose the processing into smaller steps.

It looks to me as if your input consists of a number of lines, and you want to process each line using different logic.

So start by splitting into lines with a simple `tokenize($input, '\r?\n')`;
then perhaps bind the lines to variables like

```
<xsl:variable name="lineC" select="$tokens[3]"/>
```

and then process each line with its own regular expression.